# How can i get the value of previous highest high in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, trading, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v4

trying to get the value of the previous highest high in pinescript, but this code gives me the previous bar of current highest high.

```
myper=input(50, "LENGTH")
y1 = highest(high,myper)
yy = valuewhen(high>y1[1],high,0)
plot(yy[1], linewidth=2, color=#00FF00, title="alt")
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you use the previous value (`[1]`) of the `yy` series in `plot()` function.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
myper=input(50, "LENGTH")
y1 = highest(high,myper)
yy = valuewhen(high>y1[1],high,0)
plot(yy, linewidth=2, color=#00FF00, title="alt")
```

[image]